# What would be the correct content type setting for microsoft file formats

Tags: servlets, content-type, openoffice.org

e.g `for png it's image/png`

What would be the HTTPResponse content type for the following file formats (e.g. `doc, docx, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx` and open office equivalents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc, docs - application/msword
ppt - application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
xls - application/vnd.ms-excel
```

For more see http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp